# FormsAuthentication.SignOut Fails When Setting Response Status Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

In an ASP.NET MVC3 controller action I want to to signout a user and return a 401 status code. The code is simple:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401; 
 return null;
}
```

The user is not logged out when I set the status code. Why? If I remove the status code line the user is logged out but I don't want to return a 200 status.

What's going on here? How can I acheive the desired behavior?

This is how I ended up solving the issue:

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  Response.StatusCode = 401;
  Response.Flush();
  return null;
}
else
{
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); 
   return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

Comment: This works great for non AJAX requests but doesn't work correctly for AJAX requests. See my solution in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the status code 401 (Unauthorized), the browser did not continue to save the cookies that you have previous set with the SignOut() call.

To fully SignOut you must understand that you need to left the browser the time to write down the cookies (actually clear the cookies with SignOut).

Maybe an idea is to make a redirect to a new page, and in this new page to return the status code of 401. Actually you  can use a middle page that make the SignOut and maybe other SignOut actions, then redirect to the final page that give the messages.

You can also try to call the `Response.Flush();` before the `StatusCode`, to force the browser to write down the cookies of SignOut().

Comment: You got me on the right track with Response.Flush() however Response.Flush has to be called after the status code is set. See my complete solution in the original post.